# Guidelines to prove that $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ is a transcendental number?

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

After a small search that I did I was unable to spot any answers here.What I am trying is to prove why the $2^{\sqrt2}$ is transcendental number. I know that this probably is a closed problem and probably many people have proved it already,but I want to reach the answer by myself after doing a research on this problem and going through several books and sources and test my knowledge and my power.So what I basically need is to give me guideline to solve the problem.If my question is too general,before you close it,please give me some information to rephrase,so it won't be so general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By the [Gelfond–Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_theorem),  $2^{\sqrt2}$ is transcendental.

$2^{\sqrt 2}$ is called the [Gelfond–Schneider constant](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_constant).

See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173804/deciding-whether-2-sqrt2-is-irrational-transcendental

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help.Now at least I know where I can find the answer and what to look for to gain more knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, your question is well-stated.  Some of these simply stated questions about transcendental numbers are still unknown!  I don't know about this one.  But here is another:  Is $\pi^\pi$ a rational number?  This one was unknown 20 years ago, and I expect it is still unknown.

Comment: Oh thank God.I am not experienced like you guys here.Thanks for your reply and thanks for giving me another problem to think about.(Although I do not think I will something like that.0 :)

One think I can't understand though.Why they closed this question.The users who closed it claimed that it is off-topic.Off-topic compared to what?Did I misused the tagging?

Comment: @el10780, this site is for research-level questions. For other questions, see http://math.stackexchange.com/ .


Comment: Ok.Thank you for your respond and I apologize for my ignorance.